# Are "adaptiveness" and "adaptability" interchangeable?

Tags: nouns, differences, synonyms, semantics

Here are the definitions for the words according to Cambridge dictionary:

**Adaptiveness** - the quality of being able to change to suit different condition

> Flexibility and adaptiveness are important qualities in managers.

**Adaptability** - an ability or willingness to change in order to suit different conditions

> Adaptability is a necessary quality in an ever-changing work
> environment.

I feel the takeaway is that **adaptability** could have a shade of *willingness* in some contexts. So does that mean in many others these two could be interchangeable?

Comment: In my experience, _adaptability_ is a trait applied to individuals, while _adaptiveness_ is a species or clade characteristic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no strong differences between the two in literal meaning, but *adaptability* is used far more commonly than *adaptiveness*. I have done a few searches (one in Corpus of Contemporary American English, one in British National Corpus, one in NGram) to demonstrate the difference.

### COCA

I ran a Compare search in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/). These searches highlight which words are used frequently with one term but not the other. So they can provide clues as to what contexts words tend to be used, in addition to showing raw frequency of use.

The top 25 for *adaptiveness* mostly involve words related to organizations. In actuality, almost of the top results all come from the same article: Hamid, A. A. (2017). Strategic, structural supply chain orientation and operational adaptiveness. *Journal of Business Studies Quarterly*, 9(1), p. 52-64. So *adaptiveness* is a key term the author uses to define a specific phenomenon of study in Supply Chain Orientation (SCO), but it is not a commonly used word otherwise.

*Adaptability* has more varied results. It is hard for me to distinguish a pattern in the top results: *flexibility*, *cohesion*, *family*, *change* all seem like pretty common collocations I'd expect.

### BNC

Just to make sure this isn't an American-specific thing, I also ran the same Compare search in the British National Corpus ([BNC](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/)). Similar result: *adaptiveness* is seldom used, and mostly from one source with incomplete citation information: *British Journal of Social Work*, 1991. *Adaptability* is used much more widely; I only noticed written results rather than oral interviews.

### NGram

[NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/) visualizes how infrequently *adaptiveness* is used in printed work.

[image]

*Adaptability* has long been the more common term.

### Summary

The terms may be interchangeable in literal meaning, but *adaptability* is the more common word.